# Rich Text vs XSS

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, security

I'm still a newwbie in ASP.Net and don't get how to fix the following problem.

I need rich text to be published on my project. I added [NicEdit](http://www.nicedit.com/index.php) because it seems to be easy to use.

So, as foreseen, i got an error from the server.

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client(compteRendu="blablbab<br><br>test<br>").
```

I tryed to fix it by using htmlencoder, but I failed at using it.

What I did :

```
<script type="text/VB">
    htmlEncode {
        model.compteRendu = HtmlEncode(model.compteRendu)
        }
</script>   

@Using Html.BeginForm(IsPost)
    @Html.ValidationSummary(True)
    @<fieldset>
        <legend>meeting</legend>    
    @Html.HiddenFor(Function(model) model.idmeeting)
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.compteRendu)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(Function(model) model.compteRendu)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.compteRendu)
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" onclick="htmlEncode"/>
    </p>
</fieldset>
End Using
```

So, what have I done wrong? I also tryed to do this inside the controller but I didn't find any method which was supposed to encode the Html

```
    ' POST: /Meeting/Edit/5

    <HttpPost()>
    Function Edit(meeting As meeting) As ActionResult
        meeting.compteRendu = HttpEncode(meeting.compteRendu)
        If ModelState.IsValid Then
        ...
```

ps : I'm not a native english speaker, sorry if my english sucks.

edit :
For the moment, I'm not needing more than something that allows me to replace my "new lines" by 
.

So, I've found that I could do iit like that :

```
@Html.Raw(meeting.compteRendu.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "<br />"))
```

For the moment, it's ok for me. But I'm not sure, maybe I'll need to create text with colors, and so on. So if you've an idea on how I can send validated rich text to my database, I'll be very happy.

Comment: This looks like it could answers it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client

Comment: I already found/read this topic. But I'm not really pleased by those solutions.
eg : validateRequest="false"
I also tryed to add : <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
 but it was not sufficient to validate without errors what I needed.
And then I tryed the HtmlEncode that they were talking about, successless...
btw, thx for the time sou spend by doing this research

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could decorate the `compteRendu` property on your view model with the [`<AllowHtml>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.allowhtmlattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
<AllowHtml()>
Public Property compteRendu As String
```

This will accept any characters in this property. Inside your view you don't need to do any encodings:

```
@ModelType Meeting

@Using Html.BeginForm(IsPost)
    @Html.ValidationSummary(True)
    @<fieldset>
        <legend>meeting</legend>    
        @Html.HiddenFor(Function(model) model.idmeeting)
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.compteRendu)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(Function(model) model.compteRendu)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.compteRendu)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
</fieldset>
End Using
```

Neither inside your controller action:

```
' POST: /Meeting/Edit/5

<HttpPost()>
Function Edit(meeting As meeting) As ActionResult
    If ModelState.IsValid Then
        ...
    End If
    ...
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm gonna need this further in the project!